# Why am I getting FileNotFoundException when using FileMode.OpenOrCreate?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, isolatedstorage

I am developing a simple ASP.NET WebApi application. In a controller I have a POST action that does the following code:

```
using (var isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForAssembly())
{
    using (var textWriter = new StreamWriter(
        isoStore.OpenFile(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate | FileMode.Truncate)))
    {
        // write to file
    }
}
```

which throws the `FileNotFoundException` exception on the `using` line when the file does not exist (it works fine when the file exists).

When I rewrite it as follows:

```
using (var isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForAssembly())
{
    StreamWriter textWriter;
    if (!isoStore.FileExists(filename))
    {
        textWriter = new StreamWriter(isoStore.CreateFile(filename));
    }
    else
    {
        textWriter = new StreamWriter(
             isoStore.OpenFile(filename, FileMode.Open | FileMode.Truncate));
    }
}
```

everything works fine, and I can write to the file, regardless whether it existed or not.

Isn't the purpose of `OpenOrCreate` to cover both cases from the second snippet in a single call?

Comment: Could you show an implementation of isoStore.OpenFile()?

Comment: @PawelMaga That's a method of a standard class from the `System.IO.IsolatedStorage` namespace. I've added a missing piece of code to clarify this.

Comment: Why are using bitwise OR on the FileMode Enum, which is not a bitmask? FileMode.OpenOrCreate (4 = 100) | FileMode.Truncate (5 = 101) = 5 (101) which is basically just Truncate, which requires an existing file.

Comment: @Shiffty Probably because I didn't bother to check whether it is a bitmask, and assumed it is, as that how it is often (for example in C++) :-) Thanks! (Consider posting an answer)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`FileMode` enum is not a flag type enum, which means you should not perform bitwise operations on it. `FileMode.OpenOrCreate | FileMode.Truncate` resolves to `FileMode.Truncate` which expects a file to be there.

In general `OpenOrCreate` and `Truncate` are two different modes of opening a file, so you need to chose one (`Create` being a reasonable alternative for what you need, credit to @Damien_The_Unbeliever).

Comment: I think [`Create`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode(v=vs.110).aspx) is what they want: "**FileMode.Create** is equivalent to requesting that if the file does not exist, use CreateNew; otherwise, use Truncate"